# error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown jdbcDir.create(); LUCENE INDEXING ^

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, lucene

Well , i am trying to index my database using Lucene , and here's the code.. I am just getting 1 error , not able to figure out what is it .. here's the error which i am getting "kel.java:45: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   jdbcDir.create();"

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

import org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.JdbcDirectory;

import org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.dialect.MySQLDialect;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;
import java.io.IOException;

public class kel
  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
  //code snippet to create index  
   MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

   dataSource.setUser("root");

   dataSource.setPassword("n");

   dataSource.setDatabaseName("lol");

    dataSource.setEmulateLocators(true); //This is important because we are dealing with a blob type data field  

   JdbcDirectory jdbcDir = new JdbcDirectory(dataSource, new MySQLDialect(), "ii");


   jdbcDir.create();


   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is a [**checked** exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129). This means that it **must** be caught, using a `try-catch` exception or thrown using the `throws` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose the line `jdbcDir.create()` within a `try-catch` block,

```
try {
   jdbcDir.create();
}
catch(IOException ioe){
  ioe.printStackTrace();
  logger.error(ioe.getMessage(),ioe); // if logger is implemented
}
```

or let your `main(String[] args)` throw the `IOException`.(not advisable)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

Look at the documentation of the [JdbcDirectory#create()](http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.0.1/api/org/apache/lucene/store/jdbc/JdbcDirectory.html#create()) method :

> **Throws:**
>
> IOException

Since the method throws a **checked exception** , hence you need to handle that in code by enclosing the potential exception throwing line within a `try-catch` or **inform** the code which calls your method which contains the  potential exception throwing line by adding a throws in your method declaration.